# скрытие и открытие окна javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Я реализовываю простое переключение окон, нажал Button1 (на Windows1) - открылось Windiws2, где есть Button2, нажал там уже Button2 - вернулось Windows1. Из примеров я нашел такую реализацию

```
registrationButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        registrationButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxmlFiles/registration.fxml"));

        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.showAndWait();
    });
```

В другом контроллере я делаю такой же метод, только по сути изменяю FXML файл, что по идее должно меня вернуть к изначальному окну, и как бы да, это работает, но беда с прорисовкой, она происходит только при изменении размера окна, что ни есть хорошо, я так понял это все из-за `hide();` по сути он реализует `setShowing(false);` но я не пойму как вернуть обратно отрисовку, что бы я спокойно переключался таким образом между окнами.

И в добавок, если кто-то подскажет хороший сайт со статьями по JavaFX, или актуальную книгу, буду весьма благодарен. Знаю, данный вопрос про книги уже задавали, но времена меняются, что-то устаревает. Спасибо.

Comment: Хороших книг не попадалось. И в целом подход не очень хороший. Каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку создается новая сцена на новом стейдже, а текущий видимо скрывается и больше не используется. Это "Долго, дорого и не интересно". Точно ли нет возможности решить ситуацию на одном стейдже и двумя переиспользуемыми сценами на нем?

Comment: @Maxim Я понимаю, что это немного затратнее, но данное переключение будет происходить очень редко, поэтому я решил, что данный метод не критичен, да и в принципе хочется понять, как это работает

Comment: в методе контроллера создаете полностью новую сцену. Почитайте что такое модальные окна.\

Answer (score 0):

ЭХ, как всегда после долгого тупника это оказало проще простого - медот `showAndWait();`в данном случае не подходит, всего навсего его необходимо заменить на `show();`